# Knockoutjs remove multiple by selecting checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a list of "assets" that I am displaying using foreach bind.
Each asset has a delete button which calls $parent.removeAsset, which all works fine.

However, I want to add the option to select several "assets" by checking a checkbox, and then remove all the "assets" that are checked.

I am still learning the ropes of knockoutjs so I would really appreciate any help.

Here is the code I am using to display the "assets

```
<div style="height: 100%; overflow: auto;"  data-bind="foreach: assets">
    <!-- AssetList AssetItem Tmpl BEGIN -->
    <div class="asset-item action" data-tooltip="Select Asset">
        <div class="asset-type" data-bind="css: type">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="asset-select"><input type="checkbox" /></div>
         <!-- ko if: type() === 'Text' -->
            <div class="asset-name" data-bind="text: content"></div>
         <!-- /ko -->
         <!-- ko if: type() === 'Image' -->
            <div class="asset-name">Image</div> 
         <!-- /ko -->
         <!-- ko if: type() === 'Video' -->
            <div class="asset-name">Video</div> 
         <!-- /ko -->
        <div class="asset-remove-cell">
            <div class="asset-remove action" data-tooltip="Remove Asset" data-bind="click: $parent.removeAsset"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- AssetList AssetItem Tmpl END -->
</div>
```

And this is my delete function:

```
self.removeAsset = function(asset){
    if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this asset?")) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();            
        return false;
    }
    self.selectedIndex(0);
    $.ajax({
      url: "/Assets/delete/"+asset.id(),
      type: "POST",
      success: function(response) {
          self.assets.remove(asset);
          //notify('good',response);
      }
    });

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kenneth suggested I added a boolean to my assets and then looped through the observable array and deleted each asset that was set to true. Here is the code I used for anyone looking to do something similar:

The array:

```
function Asset() {
    var self = this;
    self.id         =   ko.observable("");
    self.type       =   ko.observable("");
    self.selected   =   ko.observable(false);
};
```

The delete checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selected" />
```

The function called when the delete button is pressed:

```
$('#deleteMultipleAssets').click(function(){
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the selected asset?')) {
         ko.utils.arrayForEach(viewModel.assets(), function(asset) {
            if(asset.selected()){
                viewModel.removeMultipleAsset(asset);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The removeMultipleAssets function:

```
self.removeMultipleAsset = function(asset){
  self.assets.remove(asset);
};
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, in this way the problem is recorded as solved by SO....

Answer (score 0):

You should add a field to your assets called `selected` and then bind that field to the checkbox you're displaying inside the foreach-template.

When you click on the general delete-button, you can loop over your assets and delete all the ones that have their `selected`-field equal to true and remove them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you maybe have an example of the loop to find all assets with the selected filed set to true?